# Early exit a `CNContactStoreEnumerateContactsHandler` Enumeration

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

How do you early exit a `CNContactStoreEnumerateContactsHandler` as `stop` is defined as a boolean not an object/pointer?

```
var successfulEnumeration = store.EnumerateContacts(fetchRequest, out error, (contact, stop) =>
{
        stop = true; // this does nothing of course  
});
```

In ObjC/Swift `stop` would be something like `UnsafePointer<ObjCBool>` and thus:

ObjC: `*stop = YES;`

ObjC: `stop.initialize....`

Swift: `stop.withUnsafePointer { p in p.memory = true }`

Swift2: `stop.memory = true`

Comment: +1 for providing a good example on how EnumerateContacts works, Xamarin's documentation was light on this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this might be a mistake in Xamarin.iOS, If we look at [NSSetEnumerator](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Foundation.NSSetEnumerator/) its delegate signature looks like this:

```
public delegate Void NSSetEnumerator (NSObject obj, ref Boolean stop)
```

I think it needs the ref keyword or the value you set wont change.

[CNContactStoreEnumerateContactsHandler](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Contacts.CNContactStoreEnumerateContactsHandler/) for reference

```
public delegate Void CNContactStoreEnumerateContactsHandler (CNContact contact,Boolean stop)
```

Im just going to run a test with NSSetEnumerator to see if it stops when setting stop.

**Update**
If you run the code below you will see that it actually stops when it hits 5:

```
NSSet set = new NSSet<NSNumber> (new []{
    new NSNumber(1),
    new NSNumber(2),
    new NSNumber(3),
    new NSNumber(4),
    new NSNumber(5),
    new NSNumber(6),
    new NSNumber(7),
    new NSNumber(8),
    new NSNumber(9)
});

set.Enumerate ((NSObject obj, ref bool stop) => {

    var num = obj as NSNumber;

    if (num.Int32Value == 5)
        stop = true;
});
```

Might be able to post this as an bug and fix now its open source.

Comment: Thanks, I would have expected it to a pointer (`ref`) but thought maybe I was just brain-farting on this one... I'm currently using a double try/catch to get out of it and clean everything up... ugly but had to do something to get it working. Maybe one of the Xamarin devs will chime in on this.

Comment: Is it a `bug`, but it is a breaking change to just change to the public api so they have to obsolete the existing delegate and add another... But it will get fixed so that good ;-)

Comment: Awesome, they got back really quick, nice find! Yeah dont think there is any clean workaround. Good Question.

Comment: Fixed already @ https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/pull/22 Of course it will take time to get that release in an alpha cycle, ..., but great turn around time!